# WHERE clause when defining last logon time with wildcard in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, wildcard, sccm

I did search but could not see anything relating to my question:

```
SELECT 
    vSMS_R_System.Netbios_Name0 AS 'Name',
    vSMS_R_System.Distinguished_Name0 AS 'LDAP',
    vSMS_R_System.Operating_System_Name_and0 AS 'OS Version',
    vSMS_R_System.Last_Logon_Timestamp0 AS 'Last Logon Time',
    vSMS_R_System.Active0 AS 'Active State'
FROM 
    vSMS_R_System
WHERE 
    Distinguished_Name0 LIKE '%Site Servers%' 
    AND Operating_System_Name_and0 LIKE 'Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.%'
    AND Last_Logon_Timestamp0 LIKE '%2017-02%'
```

When executing this query, no results are displayed, however removing the last line will execute the results without issues. It seems to be the wildcard for `Last_Logon_Timestamp0` that's an issue here.

I've amended the last line of the query to the below:

```
AND Last_Logon_Timestamp0 LIKE '%2017%'
```

This displays the results I need. So it seems to be the hyphen causing problems when declaring the wildcard value in my original query.

Does this information needed to be handled differently? The hyphen doesn't appear to be an illegal character, but it does appear to be preventing the information from being displayed.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Should work.  Copy paste a 2017-02 from the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `last_logon_timestamp0` is some sort of `datetime`, then you should be using `date`/`time` functions, NOT string functions.  So:

```
SELECT s.Netbios_Name0 AS Name,
       s.Distinguished_Name0 AS LDAP,
       s.Operating_System_Name_and0 AS [OS Version],
       s.Last_Logon_Timestamp0 AS [Last Logon Time],
       s.Active0 AS [Active State]
FROM vSMS_R_System s
WHERE s.Distinguished_Name0 LIKE '%Site Servers%' AND
      s.Operating_System_Name_and0 LIKE 'Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.%' AND
      s.Last_Logon_Timestamp0 >= '2017-02-01' AND
      s.Last_Logon_Timestamp0 < '2017-03-01' ;
```

Notes:

- Your code converts the column to the local date/time representation, using whatever internationalization settings happen to be set.
- A time comparison allows the database to use indexes on the column, if they are available.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Don't use single quotes for column names, because they are easily confused for string constants.  They should only be used for string and date constants.
- Try to avoid column aliases with spaces and other non-standard variables, so you don't need to escape the names.

Comment: Much appreciated Gordon. I'm fairly new to SQL, so I'm just getting my teeth into a few things. Thanks for the tips. Looking at your response, would keeping the aliases in square brackets be good standard practice?

Comment: As Gordon suggested, try to avoid column names that would require you to quote them with brackets. Having to quote a column or table name with brackets should be rare and in cases where it's really the best name for the job.

Comment: @BabyPython . . . Avoid names that require escaping with brackets or any other characters.  Why make queries harder to write?